# Is a comma required here?

Tags: punctuation

Is a comma required in the two places in the following example?

> He asked me(,) “Blah blah?“
>   My reply was(,) "Blah blah.”

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I** don't require commas there. But I'm old enough and experienced enough to follow my own rules, not those of some style manual designed to keep cub writers and their overworked editors from having to think. And even so, once I ship my copy off to the clients they do whatever they want with it. I don't get a vote.

You probably don't get a vote either, since you're asking on a Learner's site. The only person who gets a vote is the teacher who's grading your papers. He or she is the only authority who can answer this question.

When you get to University (if you're not there already), the authority will probably be a standard style manual selected by your faculty. In the US that would probably be U.Chicago, MLA, or APA.

When you start publishing papers, the authority will be your publisher.

But when you become a famous and wealthy author, you can do what Bernard Shaw did: publish your works at your own expense. Then *you* will be the authority, and some humble graduate student will establish her professional credentials by writing a dissertation on your punctuation.